# Dropdownlist Enable disable value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

How can I Insert value to database using dropdownlist item, What I want is to select Item then when I press submit button, the numeric Value will save to sql server database using asp.net vb.net code,  the problem is ,it always save 0 value in sqlserver database, even if I selected 1, 2 , 3, or 4 , the problem is the javascript, if I remove the javascript it can select the value that I want and there is no problem, but I need it to disable the value if its already selected, to avoid duplicates to the database, can someone help me to figure it out the javascript, if I try press the save button you can see that the dropdownlist is returning to its default value 0 then reset, and not saving the value that I selected from the dropdownlist thanks.............

```
   <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb"           
   Inherits="_Default"  Debug="true"%>

   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">

   <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>

     <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
          <asp:DropDownList ID = "frst" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
           <asp:ListItem value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem value="4">4</asp:ListItem>         
          </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID = "secnd" runat="server">
       <asp:ListItem value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem value="4">4</asp:ListItem>         
            </asp:DropDownList>    

               <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save"       
        OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server"></asp:Label> 

    </div>


   <script type="text/javascript">
   var ids = ['frst', 'secnd'];

    NodeList.prototype.forEach = HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach =    
      Array.prototype.forEach;
   var selected = [];
   ids = makeid(ids);
   var opts = find(ids);
   updateS(opts);
   massdisabler(opts);
   assignFunc(ids, disabler);

    function assignFunc(i, func) { //done
   var x;
   for (x = 0; x < i.length; ++x) {
    i[x].onchange = function () {
        func(this);
     };
   } 
  }

   function disabler(i) {
   console.log(selected);
   updateS(opts);
   massdisabler(opts);
  }

  function makeid(i) { //done
   var o = [];
   i.forEach(function (v) {
    o.push(document.getElementById(v))
   });
  return o;
  }

  function find(ids) { //done
   var o = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
    o[i] = {};
    ids[i].children.forEach(function (v, n) {
        o[i][n] = v;
    });
    }

   return o;
  }

  function massdisabler(op) { //done
  var y = Object.keys(op).length;
  for (var x = 0; x < y; x++) {
    var t = 0,
        l = Object.keys(opts[x]).length;
    for (var v = 0; v < l; v++) {
        t = op[x][v];

        if (selected.some(function (k) {
            if (t.value == k) {
                return true;
        }
        })) {
            t.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            t.removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function updateS(op) { //done
  var s = [],
    y = Object.keys(op).length;

   for (var x = 0; x < y; x++) {

    var t = 0,
        l = Object.keys(opts[x]).length;

    for (var v = 0; v < l; v++) {
        t = op[x][v];
        var yn = s.some(function (k) {
            if (t.value == k) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        if (t.selected && (!yn)) s.push(t.value);
      }
   }
   selected = s;
   }
  </script>

  </form>

  </body>   
   </html>
```

can someone helpme I'm trying to revise my code please do not downvote I'm just a beginner thanks this is the whole code Please help me Im doing these for weeks :

```
    Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim cs As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(cs)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Names values(@FirstValue,@SecondValue)"
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstValue", frst.SelectedItem.Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondValue", secnd.SelectedItem.Value)
    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        cn.Open()
    End If
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cn.Close()
    lblmsg.Text = "Data entered successfully!!!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Place a HiddenField, put your dropdown selected value to HiddenField (before executing any JS code). On server side get value from HiddenField. I hope this helps!

Comment: disabled controls, as well as non-selected checkboxs/radio buttons, are not sent to the server via the post or get methods. Also you have 2 </asp:DropDownList> after <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" - could that be causing a problem?

Comment: Hello did you try it. the problem,If I removed the javascript I can select and  save the value whatever value I selected in the dropdown and save it to database but if i include again the javascript and press the button it save the value 0 even if I choose other value. thanks

Comment: Hello sir can you give me a solution rather than my code, using my dropdownlist that can save any that I choose from dropdownlist, I need help sir that is the only the problem with my system, my boss wants, I just want to disable the selected numeric value in dropdownlist if it is already selected in the first dropdown thank you... the problem of that javascript is only if I press the save button it quickly postback and reset so the value that will in the database from dropdownlist1 and 2 is both Zero(0)

Answer (score 0):

take the `viewstate` or `hiddenfield` and assign the `dropdownlist` `SelectedValue` to any of these.

Your problem will resolve.

Comment: Sir Vahid can you give me a sample solutin how to do that using dropdownlist if you dont mind thanks, I need help